# What happens to the flags I use on audit questions?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags, review-audits

I haven't done a lot of flagging so far, and therefore I currently have a low number of maximum flags per day (today I only have 13 flags to give out).
If I review post in the review queues, I will often flag a post, followed by the message:

> Congratulations! This was only a test,etc.

What happens to the flag I used to mark that audit post? Will I get it back? I feel like I should get it back, since it will no longer be potentially counted as a "helpful flag", but I can see how it would be a bother to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are not technically flagging the post only the audit, the flag is not counted as helpful/disputed/declined.

Let's imagine an extreme case for a single day:

- You're given 20 review tasks;
- The system decides to present you 20 audits;
- After reviewing 20 tasks, you have still 13 flags left.

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181484/count-helpful-flags-in-review-audits) is a question that asks for the opposite behavior.