# Custom flags shouldn't be submitted if raised through review audits

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, review-audits, triage

We just received a custom flag from a user with 1k rep, on a question that was deleted via spam/abusive flags *almost an entire month ago*. Looking into the question's timeline it would seem that the user who raised the flag did so while evaluating a Triage audit, which explains how they were able to flag a deleted question despite having less than 10k rep.

I've dismissed the flag as helpful as the user probably didn't intend for it to get through, but perhaps the flag shouldn't have gone through in the first place, even if the user was expecting it to. We don't need to be handling new flags on issues that took care of themselves weeks or months ago.

Comment: And, while you're at it, please fix the [unclear behaviour](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327580/failed-known-bad-audit-after-flagging-because-im-done-was-not-enabled) which is clearly throwing off benevolent reviewers.

Comment: We would still need to resolve such flags so the flagging user is notified of the situation. Maybe add a fourth possible outcome (helpful, declined, disputed, *obsolete*)? Or reuse *disputed*?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: We can do that by adding a custom message with the "helpful" resolution, but I'm not sure it's worth the trouble.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if I've declined flags that came in this way without spotting the weirdness.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi how about FileNotFound?

Comment: Rather than auto-dismissing the flag after the fact, why not just swallow the flag at the moment it's raised and take it as a passed audit?

Comment: @Kevin: Yep that's exactly what I meant in my second paragraph.

Comment: I have no issue with this on post that were nuked.  If they were not nuked then I still think the custom flag should make its way to the mod queue.

Comment: I'd suggest passing the audit and then asking if the flag should be swallowed

Comment: I hate to be the guy asking this, but how often does this happen? How much time/effort would be saved by fixing it? That will have to be weighed against the dev cost, especially given the valid concerns TRiG raises.

Comment: Eh, sometimes it might be appropriate to flag a review audit. One that's mistakenly marked good, for example. Almost always the appropriate action for these is DV and CV manually, rather than flag, but I'm not convinced a flag would never be appropriate.

Comment: @TylerH: I have yet to see anyone flagging for that reason. And if Laurel's answer is right it's unlikely we'll ever get to see if anyone takes advantage of the bug in this manner.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While I'm sympathetic to the notion that we shouldn't silently discard these, and *more* than sympathetic to the notion that we should allow folks to flag them as though they were real, visible posts...

...The intended behavior for the past couple of years has been to just inform the flagger that the post was an audit. If they still want to flag the post for some custom reason, they can go back and do so; otherwise, they can go on with their life knowing that the post has been deleted and no further action is really necessary.

Then flagging on audits got broke. [Now, it's fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327580/failed-known-bad-audit-after-flagging-because-im-done-was-not-enabled/327896#327896), and this intended behavior has been restored. Flags on audits are *noisily* eaten and all is right with the world.

Comment: This is why I tagged my question [bug].

Comment: Yeah... Amazing what I forget in a week away. Bluefeet brought this up Monday and it took me til now to remember any of this.

Answer (score 23):

I'd be very very wary about ignoring *custom* flags. They can be used for all kinds of things. Perhaps, though, they should be clearly marked to show the moderator that they came from a review audit, which would allow the moderator to dismiss as helpful unless the text of the flag is something unusual.

People may use custom flags to point out a pattern of a user's behaviour, for example, and such custom flags *should* be evaluated by a moderator, even if they were raised on a post in a review queue.

However, if the flag is clearly marked as having been raised on a "known bad" audit, then the moderator can read the flag and, so long as its concerns are confined to *the post itself*, just dismiss it as helpful.

Answer (score 12):

**I don't think it's safe to ignore a custom flag, even one raised during an audit.** This post might have been a crystal-clear case of spam/abuse, but in other cases a user could decide a custom flag is *really* needed, maybe to report that deleting the post was wrong, or that it isn't *so* bad it should be used as audit (which happens more often than I would like). And there could be other valid reasons that I can't think of now.

Ideally, I think it should work like this: if the user chooses a custom flag during an audit, he should be notified that it is an unexpected choice, because a normal one should be enough, and moderators should be called for only to deal with unusual situations. Then the user gets a second choice: in light of the explanation of normal vs custom flags, does he still want to raise a custom one? If he decides a normal one is enough, good: he learnt how to use flags, no one was disturbed, he passed the audit, and everybody is happy; otherwise, the custom flag is sent to moderators, who check it as usual. **If there's nothing that justifies* it, the user should learn that *he chose the wrong flag*, and it should be declined. And the audit should be considered failed.** The user did get a very clear and specific warning after all!

Otherwise people will keep raising custom flags for everything.

If this second screen is too hard work, I'd say the flag should be sent to mods, and if it is not justified*, it should be declined. I understand you didn't want to punish him, but the fact is that he did something wrong, and the right alternative was very easy. If no one tells him, he'll keep doing it.

---

*To clarify, if the custom flag is "This post has been flagged as spam, but it isn't, there is indeed a link to a product, but the user states he is the author", this is what I'd call a justified custom flag, *even if the moderator disagrees* (for example because he thinks the disclosure is not clear enough). What I'd call unjustified is a flag like "This post is spam", "It's offensive", "It is not an answer", and so on, things for which we already have normal flags.

Comment: `or that it isn't so bad it should be used as audit` .... I don't think that is a good reason for a moderator flag.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is related to the recent bug, which [as I mentioned before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327739/6083675), seems to be caused by flags failing to act like they're happening as part of a review.

I find it *very, VERY* hard to believe that you would only be noticing this now if it had been around before. In fact, I remember trying to flag an audit before with a mod flag, and I failed the audit (I thought it was plagiarized from the top voted answer, but it *was* that answer `:P`).

[Some](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303846/6083675) earlier [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181487/323179) support this.

I just got an audit, and I'm going to see if I am able to submit a mod flag on it. For science!

---

It appears to have worked:

> [image: flagged audit]

Interestingly enough, after I flagged, the "I'm Done" button became enabled, and I had to click it and I passed the audit.

---

Note that [they are going to fix the flag bug soon.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281080/why-did-flagging-as-very-low-quality-result-in-audit-failure/281162?noredirect=1#comment913313_281162) I suspect that this issue will be fixed with it.